# How to SUM with CASE based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sum, case

I've been spending ages now trying to find a solution for this SUM query I've got :

```
SELECT o.id, o.ordernr, o.datetime, o.status, CONVERT(ROUND(o.shipping,2), CHAR(8)) AS shippingcosts, 
u.id AS uid, u.name, u.surname, u.address, u.number, u.zipcode, u.country, u.email, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(op.amount, CHAR(8))) AS amount,         
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(ROUND(op.pprice,2), CHAR(8))) AS pprice, 

IF(     
        u.country!= 'NL', 
        ROUND(SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN op.discount > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discount/100)))
                WHEN op.discountf > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discountf/100)))
                WHEN op.discountf = 0 && op.discount = 0 THEN (op.amount * op.pprice)
            END
        ) + o.shipping,2),
        ROUND((SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN op.discount > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discount/100)))
                WHEN op.discountf > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discountf/100)))
                WHEN op.discountf = 0 && op.discount = 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice)*1.19)
            END
        )*1.19) + o.shipping,2)
) AS total, 

GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(p.id, CHAR(8))) AS pid, 
SUM(p.weight) AS weight, 
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN users AS u ON o.uid = u.id 
INNER JOIN order_products AS op ON op.oid = o.id
INNER JOIN products AS p ON op.pid = p.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the sum of each row if op.discount is not null or when op.discountf is not null and for each row where both op.discount and op.discountf are null...

At this point it seems mysql is summing all of the totals instead..??

Somebody can help me a hand please??

Thnx in advance (a lot)

Comment: Does o.uid = u.id represent a unique row in your database? What is making the IF ELSE and CASE structure look at a unique individual?

Comment: Hi Hituptony! o.uid = u.id has multiple rows (i.e. I have multiple order_products rows joining on the user table where o.uid equals u.id) Does this answer your question?

Comment: Before I answer, why are you converting the amounts to characters?

Comment: It's a temporary solution for fixing a xhr request (it cut off the result at approximate 300 characters), why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Just some things I am noticing here....

--You are converting all your integers, or float point data types to characters? How do you want MySQL to sum on characters?

```
SELECT o.id, o.ordernr, o.datetime, o.status, CONVERT(ROUND(o.shipping,2), CHAR(8)) AS shippingcosts, 
u.id AS uid, u.name, u.surname, u.address, u.number, u.zipcode, u.country, u.email, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(op.amount, CHAR(8))) AS amount,         
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(ROUND(op.pprice,2), CHAR(8))) AS pprice,
```

-- Never seen the CONVERT function in a group_concat, this is the code the reference manual shows GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
-- Also if you keep rounding you are not going to get correct results, just throwing that out there not sure if you care or not.I think there is too much aggregation going on, and it may be confusing.

```
IF(     
    u.country!= 'NL',
```

-- Didn't you already round these in your select? Do you need to round it again here?
-- Also does each row potentially have a discount and a discountf? if they have both they would fit into your first two CASE structures, twice...
-- Looks like you also want the shipping cost based on weight,

```
    ROUND(SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN op.discount > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discount/100)))
            WHEN op.discountf > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discountf/100)))
            WHEN op.discountf = 0 && op.discount = 0 THEN (op.amount * op.pprice)
        END) + o.shipping,2),
```

-- Why are you running the same CASE structure twice? one to add *1.19?

```
    ROUND((SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN op.discount > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discount/100)))
            WHEN op.discountf > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discountf/100)))
            WHEN op.discountf = 0 && op.discount = 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice)*1.19)
        END)*1.19) + o.shipping,2)
) AS total, 

GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(p.id, CHAR(8))) AS pid, 
SUM(p.weight) AS weight, 
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN users AS u ON o.uid = u.id 
INNER JOIN order_products AS op ON op.oid = o.id
INNER JOIN products AS p ON op.pid = p.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

I would personally try to just do something like this (probably won't work just adjust the inner join):

```
SELECT * FROM products as p
(SELECT o.id, o.ordernr, o.datetime, o.status, CONVERT(ROUND(o.shipping, 2), CHAR(8)) AS     ShippingCosts,
u.id AS U_ID, u.name, u.surname, u.address, u.number, u.zipcode, u.coutnry, u.email, 
op.amount as Amount, op.pprice as Price, 
SUM((op.amount * op.pprice)-(op.discount/100)) as SubTotal, 
SUM((op.amount * op.pprice)-(op.discountf/100)) as SubTotal2,
SUM(p.weight * o.shipping) as Shipping_Charges,
SUM(SubTotal + SubTotal2 + Shipping_Charges)) as o
inner join users AS u ON o.U_ID = u.id
WHERE u.country != 'NL';
```

-- sorry I realize there is 3 inner joins now. I would aggregate all these summations to another table that says

SELECT Order Number Order ID Order Date from Orders as O
inner join Order Products as OP
ON Order ID = Order Product ID or Order ID whichever, SUM(subtotals),
group by Order ID;

Create a table to hold these fields and then just do the inner join on the user_ID corresponding to the order number or order ID, there should be a foreign key somewhere to make the joins easier

SELECT Order Id, Order Number, Order DATE, Order Shipping, Order Product, Order Amount, SUM(Order SubTotal) FROM Orders_Total
inner join users as U on o.U_ID = u.id

I didn't take into considerations the rounding or group converting that sounds like some front end stuff that a client could do, but the computations are simple, but I really do like your query, I am just trying to break it down for you, sorry there is a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

You say, "What I'm trying to achieve is to get the sum of each row if op.discount is not null or when op.discountf is not null and for each row where both op.discount and op.discountf are null..."  If that's the case, I'd suggest adding conditions to the WHEN conditions of your case statements that test specifically for NULL values rather than treating op.discount and op.discountf as though they hold values which will evaluate accordingly when compared to 0.  aka, "NULL < 0" evaluates to NULL, not zero... and i'm not sure how that will affect your case statement?  Details on working with NULL values in control statements can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

When I first looked at the query I thought I might object to its very existence... but after I took a closer look I actually wasn't offended.  That doesn't say much, as I like to write queries like this.  There's probably a cleaner way to do what you're doing, but I can't see why your way shouldn't work.  I do see a comma at the end of this line:

```
SUM(p.weight) AS weight,
```

... which I don't think you want there?  I reformatted the query a little... not better, just a little different.  Helped me be able to see more clearly exactly what you were doing.  May help others, so I'm including it below.  Others may not prefer this formatting, so I didn't introduce it as an edit to the question.  Posting this answer now on the off chance that what I've done/noticed so far might help someone else.  Will edit to improve my "answer" if/as I see anything else.

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.ordernr,
    o.datetime,
    o.status,
    CONVERT(ROUND(o.shipping,2), CHAR(8)) AS shippingcosts, 
    u.id AS uid,
    u.name,
    u.surname,
    u.address,
    u.number,
    u.zipcode,
    u.country,
    u.email, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(op.amount, CHAR(8))) AS amount,         
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(ROUND(op.pprice, 2), CHAR(8))) AS pprice, 
    IF(     
        u.country != 'NL', 
        ROUND(SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN op.discount > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discount / 100)))
                WHEN op.discountf > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discountf / 100)))
                WHEN op.discountf = 0 && op.discount = 0 THEN (op.amount * op.pprice)
            END
        ) + o.shipping, 2),
        ROUND((SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN op.discount > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discount / 100)))
                WHEN op.discountf > 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) - ((op.amount * op.pprice) * (op.discountf / 100)))
                WHEN op.discountf = 0 && op.discount = 0 THEN ((op.amount * op.pprice) * 1.19)
            END
        ) * 1.19) + o.shipping, 2)
    ) AS total, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(p.id, CHAR(8))) AS pid, 
    SUM(p.weight) AS weight,
FROM
    orders o INNER JOIN users u
        ON o.uid = u.id 
    INNER JOIN order_products op
        ON o.id = op.oid
    INNER JOIN products p
        ON op.pid = p.id
GROUP BY o.id
```